# Почему сигнатура метода Map.compute() с использованием лямбда-функции выглядит подобным образом?

Tags: java, map, lambda, java-hashmap, signature

Вот код из теории:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class WordCountExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var words = List.of("apple", "banana", "apple", "orange", "banana", "apple");
        var wordCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        words.forEach((word) -> {
            wordCount.compute(word, (key, count) -> count == null ? 1 : count + 1);
        });

        System.out.println(wordCount); // Output: {orange=1, banana=2, apple=3}
    }
}
```

Почему сигнатура функции имеет подобный вид? Строка из теории:

```
wordCount.compute(word, (key, count) -> count == null ? 1 : count + 1);
```

Если мы получаем на вход текущее значение ключа и выполняем с ним необходимые операции, то для чего второй переменной мы снова даем по сути тот же самый key? В таком виде, как `(word, count)` разве нельзя передать в `.compute()`? Почему? Что-то я упускаю, но не могу понять что именно. Если даже не брать в учет лямбда запись, то для чего здесь интерфейс `BiFunction`? Чтобы была возможность поменять значение по данному ключу, используя сам ключ при этом, хоть в учебном примере кода это не было показано?

Не вдаваясь в детали реализации и типы, что-то вроде `{orange= "orange count is 1", banana="banana count is 2", apple="apple count is 3"}`, где в значении используется и имя самого ключа, и тогда использование `BiFunction` себя оправдывает?

И в таком случае, тем не менее, я не понимаю для чего в `.compute()` отдельно передавать `key`.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Видимо не понимаю чего-то важного

Comment: _для чего в .compute() отдельно передавать key_ - например, чтобы не делать замыкание.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод [`Map<K, V>::V compute(K k, (K key, V value) -> ...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) вычисляет новое значение для заданного ключа `key` на основании существующего значения `value`, которое *может быть* равно `null`, если ключа `k` в данной мапе *пока* не существует.

> Если мы получаем на вход текущее значение ключа и выполняем с ним необходимые операции, то для чего второй переменной мы снова даем по сути тот же самый `key`? В таком виде, как `(word, count)` разве нельзя передать в `.compute()`?

В данном случае переменная `word` уже определена в лямбде для метода `forEach`, и она может передаваться только как первый параметр в метод `compute`, который ожидает другую лямбда-функцию *со своими аргументами*.
При попытке использовать *то же название* `(word, count) -> ...` возникнет
ошибка компиляции `error: variable word is already defined`, поэтому данную лямбду следует определить со своим названием для аргумента `key`, уникальным в контексте данного метода: `.compute(word, (key, count) -> ...)`.

Разумеется, вместо значения `key` при вызове лямбды будет подставляться значение из переменной `word`.

Если рассмотреть подробнее пример из вопроса, при первой попытке вычислить *значение* для ключа "apple":

```java
var words = List.of("apple", "banana", "apple", "orange", "banana", "apple");
var wordCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

words.forEach((word) -> {
    wordCount.compute(word, (key, count) -> count == null ? 1 : count + 1);
});
```

лямбда будет вызвана с параметрами `("apple", null)`, так как ключ не найден и этот `null` следует обработать.  При второй попытке `count` уже не будет `null`: `("apple", 1) -> 1 + 1`.

В частности поэтому использование аналогичной функции [`Map::merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) может выглядеть логичнее / понятнее: ключу соответствует некоторое значение по умолчанию, и затем вызывается функция для модификации *текущего значения* `(V oldVal, V newVal) -> oldVal + newVal` (которое всегда будет существовать в мапе).

```java
words.forEach((word) -> {
    wordCount.merge(word, 1, Integer::sum);
});
```

Comment: Слава анонимным минусаторам!